# MySql Syntax (Join, UNION ALL)?

Tags: mysql

Ok. So I have a table called jos_sobi2_fields_data that contains multiple fids and sections. For example the baseDate from fid=36 contains "Names" and the baseData from fid=39 contains "Addresses" I need to write a query that is going to select data from jos_sobi2_fields_data and put the Names in one column and the address in one beside it. So far I've tried

```
Select baseDate 
from jos_sobi2_fields_data 
WHERE fid=36 
and section = 54; 
UNION ALL 
Select baseData 
from jos_sobi2_fields_data 
WHERE fid=39 
AND section = 54;
```

But when I query this it just lists the baseData from fid=36 first and then under it, it lists the baseData from fid=39. So how do I get it two separate the two into separate columns beside eachother?

P.S. The section is just regarding information from one specific website, so another website might be section = 52.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use a join... something like this maybe:

```
SELECT jsfdName.baseData AS Name, jsfdAddr.baseData as Address
FROM jos_sobi2_fields_data AS jsfdName
JOIN jos_sobi2_fields_data AS jsfdAddr USING( section, sid )
WHERE jsfdName.fid = 36 AND jsfdAddr.fid = 39
    AND section = <section>
```

Replace `<section>` with the section number (or a prepared statement placeholder, even better).

Comment: It's missing the section filter (like `jsfdName.section = 54`), but that's what I'd use.

Comment: Where are you getting the jsfdName and jsfdAddr? I don't have those tables. The information is stored in the same table....

Comment: This line here: `jos_sobi2_fields_data jsfdName` reads the table you have and aliases it as `jsfdName`. Same for the `jsfdAddr`. We're joining the table to itself, so we need to alias it.

Comment: @TheVedge Thanks, I'll fix that now!

Comment: Ok. I gotcha now. Unfortunately, when I run this command, it only grabs one Name so like Justin is repeated for all the address.... Any ideas?

Comment: Is there something else to match on? Could you provide a few rows of data for each `fid`? If you're getting the same Name on multiple rows, that means that there are multiple Address fields with the same `section` as the Name field.

Comment: I don't think that I could join on anything else. Basically under section 54 there are fids 36-38. 36 contains names, 37 contains addresses and 38 contains zip codes.

Comment: The problem that I'm having is that fid=36 contains the baseData of names while fid=37 contains the baseData of addresses, etc. when I did the command with a union all it listed all the names and then all the addresses, but they were in one column and I need them separated into two columns. Is there another command that I could use besides join?

Comment: What is the relationship between Names and Addresses? There needs to be a way to connect them.

Comment: @RyanP - I think you need to add itemid to the join criteria. A quick google search found the schema.

Comment: ok. I tried that but it says unknown column name itemid.... I looked more into the database and I'll see if I can explain this better. It has the attributes fid, sid, section and baseData. section 54 contains the information I need from the database and all the information is stored in the baseData column, but the data being seen depends on the fid. So for example, fid 36 in section 54 would display Walmart, where fid 37 in section 54 would show (Walmart's address). Then, when I looked back into the database i saw another column named sid.

Comment: This column increase from 330 until the last entry, but I did notice that the sid for Walmart (fid=36 section=54) is 330 and the sid for Walmart's address (fid=37 section=54) is also 330. Does this help any?

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much for working through this with me @RyanP  :)